# Navbar Collapse is not longer working, despite making no changes to it directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap navbar collapse, which until yesterday was working fine. However I downloaded bootstrap and jquery rather than using the cdn and deferred my javascript dependencies and it no longer works.

Here is the code:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.12.min.js"></script>
    <link defer type="text/javascript" href="/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="/lightgallery/dist/js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="width: 100%">
    <!-- <script src="test.js"></script> -->
    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="/js/homepage.min.js"></script>
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
        <div class="container-fluid col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-12">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="padding: 0;">
                    <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="" style="height: 100%; width: auto;">
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a class="fa">|</a></li>
                    <li><a class="fa fa-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fa fa-instagram" href="http://www.instagram.com/"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="fa fa-twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com/"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Try with another latest version of `jquery`.

Comment: Please try to remove the defer attribute from your script tags and see if it works.

Comment: Removing the defer tag does not work, I will try the latest jquery.

Comment: updated jquery, had no effect on the current error.

Comment: I dont find bootstrap.min.css included in the code?... it is working fine for me... here is the link    https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/wwsg8y4m/2/

Comment: it's included at the end of the file rather than the beginning (this is just a snippet of the top), would that cause the issue?